# How do I test specific cases in unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have read the python documentation for unittest and found it a bit confusing. I have written a test file with methods for testing various classes and methods, along the lines of:

```
class test_class_Graph(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        test_graph = Graph()
    def test_method__init__(self):
        assertEquals(x, y)
    def test_method_node(self, name):
        node = test_graph.node(name)
        assertIsInstance(node, Node)
        assertEquals(node.name, name)
class test_class_Node(unittest.TestCase):
    etc
```

I have created some test-methods with 'if-else' statements, corresponding to 'if-else' statements in the actual methods. These are a kind of test-case - under certain conditions, the method should act one way, under other conditions, we expect the method to produce something different.

There are certain cases where I don't want to partition the set of possible conditions into 'if-else' statements, I just want to test a few 'samples' for more complicated methods. For example, if the input is a specific 'X', I want the output to be a specific 'Y'.

Where do I write specific test cases like this? Am I supposed to run my tests from the command line, entering inputs there? Or am I supposed to simply execute a test file from the command line with 'run', and somehow have a sequence of pre-selected inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: You may want to clarify with more specific descriptions of exactly what you're trying to do, but I think I get the general idea.

Comment: Use `setUp`, not `__init__` (but keep your `setUp` methods very simple, or omit them entirely).

Answer (score 0):

---

It sounds like you have a long program with lots of `input()` calls and things. What I would do to test this is try to move as much of your actual program code into functions, so that your main is just prints and inputs, which send the data to functions. Those functions then return data, which you print. Then you can test those functions with the input. So this would be your user-interacting code:

```
def main():
    x = input('what is your x?')
    y = input('what is your y?')
    z = input('And what is your z?')
    print(process_data(x, y, z))
```

Then you can test your logic like this:
Ah, I see, that was using unittest.

```
from mycode import process_data

class TestDataProcessing(unittest.TestCase):
    def try_one_thing(self):
        result = process_data(11, 44, 'Steve')
        assertEquals(result, 99)

    def try_another_thing(self):
        result = process_data(2, 6, 'Alan')
        assertEquals(result, 12)
```

Make sense?

Comment: Well, that would be a great way to test the code, I agree. But I want to use unittest for a variety of reasons. The heart of my question was how we use unittest files - do we include samples of input and expected output in the file somewhere, or do we run the tests by entering the test inputs from the command line?

Comment: Because I've read that if you 'run' a testcase it will just automatically run all the test methods. I don't understand how it can do this without being fed input, however.

Comment: That was using unittest! That's exactly how you do it. You add methods which try different inputs and compare them to expected outputs. I expanded on the example to show what it would look like.

Comment: @jukhamil unittest is intended for fully automated testing without interactive user input.  Also, the test suite is not expected to take any required arguments on the command line (except to specify which tests to run).